# Create database fields to an existing table when installing a module in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-hooks, drupal-entities

I'm new to drupal and I need some help.

I created a new module with name `user_extra`. Which create necessery table when Installing the module.

But I also need to insert some database field in `'users_field_data'` table (`'user_extra_id'` and `'user_office'`)

In `baseFieldDefinitions` I wrote all necessery database table fields for `user_extra` table.

```
 public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    // Standard field, used as a unique if primary index.
    $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
        ->setLabel(t('Unit ID'))
        ->setDescription(t('The unit ID.'))
        ->setReadOnly(TRUE)
        ->setSetting('unsigned', TRUE);

    $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
        ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
        ->setDescription(t('The unit UUID.'))
        ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
        .
        .
        .
    $fields['user_info'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
        ->setLabel(t('User Info'))
        ->setDescription(t("The User Info"))
        ->setSetting('max_length', 255)
        ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
          'type' => 'string_textfield',
          'weight' => 10,
        ))
        ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
     return $fields;
     }
```

When I install the module it inserts all values that I define in `baseFieldDefinitions`.

**But I also need to create `'user_extra_id'` and `'user_office'` in `'users_field_data'` table with `setDisplayOptions` and `setDisplayConfigurable` options.**

This is the commenting that I made in entity file

```
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "user_extra",
 *   label = @Translation("user extra"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\user_extra\UserextraStorage",
 *     "storage_schema" = "Drupal\user_extra\UserextraStorageSchema",
 *     "access" = "Drupal\user_extra\UserextraAccessControlHandler",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\user_extra\UserextraListBuilder",
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\user_extra\UserextraViewBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\user_extra\UserextraViewsData",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\user_extra\Form\UserextraForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\user_extra\Form\UserextraAddForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\user_extra\Form\UserextraEditForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\user_extra\Form\UserextraDeleteForm",
 *     }
 *   },
 *   admin_permission = "administer user_extra",
 *   base_table = "user_extra",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/user_extra/{user_extra}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/user_extra/add",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/user_extra/{user_extra}/delete",
 *     "overview-form" = "/admin/user_extra/${user_extra}/overview",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/user_extra/{user_extra}",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/user_extra",
 *     "children" = "/admin/user_extra/{user_extra}/children",
 *   },
 * )
 */
```